# Spring Data jpa query with Join with where condition

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have two tables

- `RoleMasterLink` with `userId` and `RoleId`
- `RoleMaster` with `RoleId` and `FunctionalRole`

I need to achive

`Select rm.FunctionalRole from RoleMaster rm join RoleMasterLink rml on rml.RoleId = rm.RoleId where rml.userId='yesh'`

User can have many roleIds, I need to get FunctionalRole based on RoleId

How to achive this with Spring Data Jpa, gone through many links but exactly couldn't get.

Comment: What do you want as return type? String?

Comment: Return type will be List of Strings , say User ID has three RoleIds, we should match and get the Functional Roles. Looks like simple requirement but I am missing some annotations in model class.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add your query in a @Query annotation in your Repository interface:

```
@Query("Select rm.FunctionalRole from RoleMaster rm join RoleMasterLink rml on rml.RoleId = rm.RoleId where rml.userId= :userId")
String findFunctionalRole(String userId);
```

Comment: I tried same query , can you give code, like in RoleMasterLink and RoleMaster which annotations should I give to achive this, like join Column () and one-to-one and mapping by...

Comment: Can you please post the classes RoleMaster and RoleMasterLink ?